# Travis CI Build failure due to failed to execute openssl command

Tags: travis-ci

In a [open source project](https://github.com/arnabk/java-dogstatsd-client/pull/7) I am seeing the travis build failing with the below message:-

```
The command "openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD -in secring.gpg.enc -out local.secring.gpg -d" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

The full log can be viewed on the travis [console](https://travis-ci.org/arnabk/java-dogstatsd-client/builds/152728919). The config can be viewed [here](https://travis-ci.org/arnabk/java-dogstatsd-client/jobs/152728920/config).

Can someone suggest me why this error is coming and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I ran into the same problem today.

Comment: No. Did you find one?

Comment: For me it was because I copied an encrypted file and travis configuration from one project and moved it to another. Apparently, that does not work. I don't know the details why not... but basically you have to re-encrypt the data for every project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone has [encrypted the file](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/) `local.secring.gpg`for Travis and stored it as `ecring.gpg.enc`, but Travis is now not able to decrypt it. The password is apparently not correct.

Comment: This was caused by us uploading a new encrypted `Info.plist` and an old branch not being able to decrypt. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.